# Using Column Alias as Values in other columns of table in Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table that has columns FundId, BreakdownName, BreakdownType and BreakdownValue

```
FundId     BreakdownName   BreakdownType BreakdownValue
F00000OCVS  Cash               Long         10.69
F00000OCVS  Cash               Net          3.17
```

I want result table show fundid and Breakdownvalue as alias of combination of breadkdownname and breakdowntype

so for example, above table should result into

```
FundId      CashLong   CashNet
F00000OCVS  10.69       3.17
```

I tried doing it with case statement as

```
select
a.FundID,
b.CashLong,
b.CashNet
from  a
 inner join ( select FundID,
    case when BreakdownName = 'Cash' and BreakdownType = 'Long' then BreakdownValue end as 'CashLong',
    case when BreakdownName = 'Cash' and BreakdownType = 'Net' then BreakdownValue end as 'CashNet'
from Morningstar.dbo.mstardatawarehouseassetallocationbreakdownvertical
where FundShareClassID = 'F00000OCVS') b
on a.FundShareClassID = b.FundShareClassID
where a.FundShareClassID = 'F00000OCVS'
```

But this is giving me multiple rows for fund. First row has value for CashLong but CashNet is null. Second row has value for CashNet but CashLong is null. I want to have them in single row.

I tried doing it using temp table and insert but same result.

Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Do you have only those two columns every time? Or does this need to be a dynamic solution?

Comment: Table has BreakdownName and BreakdownType for every fund id. There are 12 more combinations like Cash and Long = CashLong but they are static. Their wont be random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do easily with conditional aggregation. Something like this.

```
select bdv.FundId
    , CashLong = max(case when bdv.BreakdownType = 'Long' then bdv.BreakdownValue end)
    , CashNet = max(case when bdv.BreakdownType = 'Net' then bdv.BreakdownValue end)
from Morningstar.dbo.mstardatawarehouseassetallocationbreakdownvertical bdv
group by bdv.FundId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the pivot function in sql server:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017
This should be able to "flip" rows with colums as you seem to need here.

You might need to combine the pivot function with a subquery to prepare your data (e.g. concat BreakdownName and BreakdownType together, then use that column for pivoting. I would post some example code but I don't have a sql server at hand atm.)